# Are question about selling chess equipment on topic?

Tags: discussion

I own a payed 'lifetime' subscription to a popular chess playing site which I'd like to sell.

I want to ask on the main site what are the best places to sell chess stuff, in particular recommendations for selling my account. Since Ebay doesn't work for me, the question would point out that an ideal answer will offer some alternatives.

If the community decides it is on topic, I also want to ask what tags I should add to the question.

Below I leave a sketch (which might or might not be final depending on the answers/vote score to this meta question).

> I own a payed 'lifetime' subscription to a popular chess playing site which I'd like to sell.
>   What are the best [e-commerce](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E-commerce) websites to sell chess stuff, in particular my account? Since Ebay doesn't work for me, an ideal answer will include other alternatives.

Comment: I do not think your question would be on topic. Some moderator should verify this, because I am not 100% sure...

Comment: @AlwaysLearningNewStuff I suspected so. In any case the general disinterest for this question on meta is possibly an indicator that it would be ignored on the main site too. I decided to assume it is off topic until contrary evidence. Thank you for your input.

Comment: Best regards, and god luck in selling your account...